# Firebase Realtime Database Web Interface Visual Bug

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-console

So today I encountered something strange while looking at the new Realtime Database interface. While I was testing something which involved the deletion of some data I noticed this:

[image]

Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTICm.jpg

Basically the node *bRqT3dAc5JhNWv0616lawe6w9Ln1* gets deleted by a cloud function with a simple `remove()` call on its reference. But as you can see in the video while it is getting deleted a few duplicates appear and get deleted immediately. I tested it for a while but the behavior seems to be random. It also sometimes happens when I try to delete some other node in the database but from the client.

This is why I think this is a visual bug and not a bug in my code:

1. The code is more than a year and half old and thus I have tested it countless times before and I have never seen this happen before.
2. There aren't any unexpected results from the code execution. This means that the database looks exactly as it should at the end of the code execution.

Since the only thing that has changed recently is the web interface for the database I think that this must be a visual bug, but I am still not 100% certain. Can someone else please confirm if this indeed is just a visual bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

That indeed looks like a visual glitch that was introduced in a major update to our data viewer that was released a couple of weeks ago. As you said, it doesn't impact the data that is stored or even read, but it is definitely a bug.

From what I heard, our QA team just caught this one late last week too, but just to be certain: can you [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) with our support team for it, so they can track it too?